# RewriteRule for folder in folder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have a following record in my sites-available/default:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName example.com
        DocumentRoot /home/git/www/public_html
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/git/www/public_html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride  All
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel debug

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

ServerAlias *.example.com
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((.*)\.)example.com$
  RewriteRule /(.*) /%2/$1

</VirtualHost>
```

But, I need my sites redirecting to /(.*)/public_html, where located index.php file.

How can I redirect the request to a sub folder, to display the content for the subdomain?

I can't use DocumentRoot /home/git/ because I have next structure of the server:

`/home/git/www/public_html/`
public_html contain other projects, e.x: 004, 003, 001
Each project contain public_html folder too, with index.php file.

And when I enter in URL : 004.example.com I need to use `/home/git/www/public_html/004/public_html/index.php`  file.

When I enter in URL : 001.example.com path to the file should be: `/home/git/www/public_html/001/public_html/index.php`

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe first setting your document root to `git`:

```
DocumentRoot /home/git/
```

Then restrict direct access to public_html

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(.*)public_html/([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.example.com/%2 [L,R=301]
```

Canonicallize the www:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Then internally rewrite to the public_html

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public_html/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/public_html/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I can't use DocumentRoot /home/git/ because I have next structure of the server:

/home/git/www/public_html/ public_html contain other projects, e.x: 004, 003, 001 Each project contain public_html folder too, with index.php file.

And when I enter in URL : 004.example.com I need to use /home/git/www/public_html/004/public_html/index.php file.

When I enter in URL : 001.example.com path to the file should be: /home/git/www/public_html/001/public_html/index.php